# SendGrid anchor <a> tag is not working properly in Outlook

Tags: node.js, email, outlook, sendgrid

I used Sendgrid api for email template and in one of email has some confirmation functionality and for that I used  an anchor  tag which is redirecting to backend server and then backend api did all stuff. It is working fine, but some of outlook clients are complaining that they are not redirecting to the correct address.

I got the link from the client (outlook) which is something below:

https://owa.nexus.ox.ac.uk/owa/redir.aspx?SURL=u16WQnU.......

but above link is wrong and in sendgrid the link should be something like below:

https://u3550765.ct.sendgrid.net/wf/click?upn=hj8lklPLwDMw.......

Can anyone help me and suggest me either it is sendgrid issue in Outlook or it is something related to Outlook setting ?

Below is the email template:

```
  <div style="width: 500px;margin: auto;margin-top: 37px;">
    <div class="rest-btn" style="display: inline-block;margin: 10px;width: 200px;color: #fff;height: 40px;border: none;border-radius: 5px;line-height: 2.9;text-align: center;border: 1px solid #ccc;padding: 0px;background-color: #4dbc39;">
      <a href="{{ baseURL }}” style="color: white !important;text-decoration:none">ACCEPT</a>
    </div>
    <div class="rest-btn" style="display: inline-block;margin: 10px;width: 200px;height: 40px;border: none;border-radius: 5px;color:#ffffff;line-height: 2.9;text-align: center;padding: 0px;border: 1px solid #ccc;padding: 0px;background-color: #4dbc39;">
      <a href="{{ baseURL }}" style="color:white;text-decoration:none">DECLINE</a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the issue is you're using Outlook specific HTML ([VML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee384217(v=vs.85).aspx)) to generate buttons. SendGrid doesn't wrap those links, which is why that isn't working.

It would be helpful if you could post a sample of the HTML you sent. Then we could confirm if that's the issue.

Comment: I have updated my question with email template that I am using, plz check it.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm sure this isn't the whole template. Were you able to reproduce the issue with this snippet? The part i'm looking for should be between something like `<!--[if mso]>…<![endif]-->`